# ModelState.AddModelError alternative

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ModelState.AddModelError to display error message to user when Model do not pass validation. What is the best method do display information message when validation is passed. I do not want to add additional HTML elements. Can I use ModelState object to send information messages?

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the model is valid and display a corresponding message

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div>Your model is valid</div>
}
```

Obviously if you don't want this to be displayed all the time even when you first arrive at the page you could use an additional view model boolean property to indicate whether you want to display the message or not. Then inside your POST action set its value to true when everything passes validation and in the view:

```
@if (Model.ShouldShowSuccess && ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div>Your model is valid</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a PartialView to display success posts.
It's near the Html.ValidationSummary().

When a ModelState is valid I value a TempData variable with the IsValid message, so in my View I have this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()

@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && TempData["ModelIsValidMsg"] != null)
{ 
    @Html.Partial("PostSuccess", TempData["ModelIsValidMsg"])
}
```

In my Controller:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    TempData["ModelIsValidMsg"] = "Your success msg";
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Your error msg");
}
```

Inside the PartialView I display the TempData message.